# printf printing garbage number

Tags: assembly, x86, printf

I am scratching my head to for 8 hours, just to print sum of two numbers in assembly.

Here's my simple code:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none

.data
msg     dd  32h
str1 db "Hello",0
fmt    db "Sum: %X",0

.data?
retvalue dd ?

.code
include windows.inc
include user32.inc
includelib user32.lib
include kernel32.inc
includelib kernel32.lib
includelib MSVCRT
extrn printf:near
extrn exit:near

public main
main proc


         mov eax, 17h       ; 23
         mov ecx, 1Eh     ; 30
         add eax, ecx
         mov retvalue,eax
         ;push offset retvalue
         push offset msg
         ;push offset str1
         push offset fmt
         call printf 
         push 0
         call exit

main endp

end main
```

The Problem is that the final printf prints rubbish numbers:

here's the output: `Sum: 403000`

Expected output : `Sum: 53`

EDIT:

When i try to do the following , it doesn't work

```
  push retvalue
  ;push  msg
  push str1
  push  offset fmt
  call printf
```

And i have changed my `fmt`:

`fmt db "%d & %s",0`

Error:

> (32) : error A2070: invalid instruction operands

EDIT2:

Still after passing offset of `str1` still the program does compile and links, but doesn't seem to run.

Error:

`myapp.exe has stopped responding`

Code:

`fmt    db "%d & %s",0`

```
  push retvalue
  ;push  msg
  push offset str1
  push  offset fmt
  call printf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as shown prints the address of `msg` since you do `push offset msg`. `printf` expects the value to print, not a pointer to it. As such, this should work:

```
     mov eax, 17h       ; 23
     mov ecx, 1Eh     ; 30
     add eax, ecx
     push eax
     push offset fmt
     call printf
```

Comment: When i try to print both string and Sum, it fails. See my edit

Comment: Funnily enough, strings do expect a pointer (since they are `char*`)

Comment: Now you got the argument order wrong, the format string expects the string second but you pass it as first (since you use `push`, order is reversed)